# How to understand Reference number for administrators or support: #6CEBBCA5

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I'm using MS CRM 2011 On-Pre, In the Trace file i found below line in error message attribute

" Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #6CEBBCA5"

How can I analyze the code, Is there any entity where I can find all the error code.

Please suggest I'm totally confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code itself doesn't carry any intrinsic meaning - it is simply a unique string that can be searched for within a trace log file to help pinpoint logs that are pertinent to your issue.

[More info here](http://blogs.infinite-x.net/2011/04/03/crm-2011-tracing-errors-during-sdk-development/)